# Have div take 100% of document width under horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll, width

Sorry for what must be a very silly question.

I have a div #header, and a div #content. The contents of #content may be wide, even wider than the viewport. In this case, a horizontal scrollbar appears, which is fine.

However, with the horizontal scrollbar, I would want #header to take 100% of the width, not of the viewport, but of the document; so that it is not interrupted when the user scrolls.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header" style="background:red;">this should take the entire width, even when
    scrolling to the right</div>
  <div id="content" style="min-width:1000px; min-height:1000px; border:1px solid green;">this causes a horizontal
    scrollbar on narrow displays</div>
</body></html>
```

Here is an example: http://a3nm.net/share/test_157235.html

I would want the red #header div to be as wide as #contents underneath. For the example I emulated #content being wide with min-width, but in general I would like a method that works no matter what width #contents happens to have.

Note that if #content is sufficiently high to cause *vertical* scrolling, I want the header to scroll away with the top of the content when the user scrolls downwards.

I am sure that this can be done in Javascript, but I would be looking for a pure CSS solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I found a way. First, set html and body to have margin and padding of 0 as a CSS reset would:

```
html, body
{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Next, enclose both #header and #content in a div #wrapper with the style:

```
#wrapper
{
  position:absolute;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

This makes wrapper take up at least 100% of the viewport width (resulting in no horizontal scrollbar thanks to the CSS reset), and it being absolute makes it somehow take 100% of the document width in case a horizontal scrollbar is required because of #content.

Complete solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <style type="text/css">
  html,body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div style="position:absolute; min-width: 100%;">
  <div id="header" style="background:red;">this should take the entire width, even when
    scrolling to the right</div>
  <div id="content" style="min-width:1000px; min-height:1000px; border:1px solid green;">this causes a horizontal
    scrollbar on narrow displays</div>
  </div>
</body></html>
```

Resulting in: http://a3nm.net/share/test_971696.html

Answer (score 1):

`width:100%` will only make an element as wide as its parent; in this case the viewport. The solution to your question as best as I understand it is to essentially *pin* the header within the viewport rather than expanding its width:

```
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
```

Elements with `position: fixed;` appear outside the regular flow of elements on the page, so you'll need to add margin to the top of your main content div to compensate. So if the height of your header is 50px, you'll need to add `margin-top: 50px;` to the content wrapper.

All that said, I would suggest making the main content responsive to various screen widths rather than allowing horizontal scrollbars - horizontal scrollbars typically make for a poor user experience.

Edit: If you need the header to *not* be pinned for vertical scrolling, I'm not sure a pure CSS solution exists. You could hide the header element on scroll with javascript.

Comment: Thanks! This almost does what I want, except that when scrolling *vertically* I do not want the div to remain fixed, I want it to scroll with the rest of the content. Is this possible? (I should have mentioned this in the original question, I edited it.)

Comment: @a3nm : Updated my answer. There isn't any pure-CSS method I'm aware of to set fixed positioning on just one direction. You can achieve that with some JS, however.

Comment: surely this can be done with Javascript, but I would prefer a purely CSS answer. I updated the question to reflect this. Thanks!

Comment: Why you want to avoid JS? Did there any specific reason?

Comment: Just general reasons: JS is expensive to execute, and it is not supported by all browsers and all browser configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with Eric Meyers reset css?
You need to set your #header('s) padding and margin to 0.

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this, but it doesn't seem to fix the problem, see http://a3nm.net/share/test2_699666.html

Comment: Just so I'm sure about your problem. You want your header to fill the whole 100% width. And your content not?

Comment: I want the red header to fill 100% of the width, including what is at the right when I scroll to the right. The content will also end up taking up 100% of the width, but I don't know in advance what the width of the content will be

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>
 <style>
    body {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .wrapper {
        margin:0 auto;
        width:1000px;
        min-width:1000px;
        background:green;
        border:1px solid green;
    }
    footer {
        background:blue;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<header style="background:red;">
 This should take the entire width, even when scrolling to the right
</header>
<div class="wrapper">
This causes a horizontal scrollbar on narrow displays

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Okay, so what I've done is to change your div's. There is a semantic tag called header which is just as good if not better than your div. But what you are asking about is some styling for your divs.
You need to add a margin: 0 auto; which center your div. In this case the wrapper, where you will have your content.
I also added margin and padding 0 because you want the header to fill the full width.

Sorry for my bad english. :-)

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work either : http://a3nm.net/share/test2_821611.html -- when displaying this in a narrow window and scrolling to the right, the header in red still stops before the right end of the document.

Comment: You can always change the min-width to 1000px the same as wrapper and have the width set to 100%, that will help the header be as long as wrapper or longer when the window is bigger than 1000px.

Comment: min-width is only an example, for my real use case #content may end up being wider than 1000px and wider than the window, in a way that I can't control